# Access form linked to disconnected ADODB.Recordset: save changes

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, adodb

I am trying to set up a form to use a disconnected ADODB.Recordset as its source.
The issue I have is that changes are *not* saved into the original Access table upon closing the form and replying "Yes" to the prompt. What am I missing ?

Note: Please don't tell me the method is useless, it's just a POC with a local table, I plan to try later with a more "distant" recordset.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        rs.Open "select * from amsPor", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic
        Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End With
    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    conn.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Select Case MsgBox("Save changes ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
    Case vbNo
        'do nothing
    Case vbYes
        conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection
        rs.ActiveConnection = conn
        rs.UpdateBatch
        rs.Close
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
    Case vbCancel
        Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Take a small table which has a primary key
- Generate an automatic form with it
- Save the form.
- Add the above code to the form, replacing the table name in the `select` clause.
- Empty the `Record Source` property of the form.
- Save and Close the form.
- You can open the form and make changes to the data. Upon close, you will be prompted for saving your changes.

---

**EDIT**: I wonder if the issue might be in the `CurrentProject.Connection` ?
In the debug window, I typed `? CurrentProject.Connection` and got the following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=\\xxxxxx\yyyy$\Documents\AMS.accdb;Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\G828992\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't closing the record set nor the connection.  Try that?

Comment: Is there any chance that `conn` and `rs` are being reset between `Form_load` and `Form_Unload`? I know global variables can be really finicky and lose their values if an error occurs.

Comment: @Aiken: They are not reset: it would trigger an error, which is not the case. I traced the whole process and it runs as expected, except for the fact that the underlying table is not updated.

Comment: @iDevlop Ah no worries, it's probably just a bit of a knee-jerk reaction to global variables on my part.

Comment: Might try changing its type from a 'Static' recordset to another type when first opened?  Changes might be ignored when data is reconnected?

Comment: @iDevlop  It just occured to me that if your "remote" DB is Access you would have a bunch of problems and/or reduced functionality because ADO is not good in this case: one should, actually must use DAO.

Comment: You're missing a `conn.Close` in `Form_Unload(...)`

Comment: Is this code used in multiuser environment?

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, i won't even suggest to change code from ADO to DAO. The reason in 3 words: DAO is old.

Comment: @Maciej It will take more than just 3 words... As long a we are dealing with Access, DAO is alive and well, thank you. Please examine, for example, [Microsoft Data Access Objects reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn124645%28v=office.15%29.aspx), or [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799%28v=office.15%29.aspx), or [Recordset Object (DAO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: @GeneSkuratovsky, ADO and DAO is alive, but the difference is like between boy and old-man ;)
Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: @MaciejLos: not really intended for multiuser environment. It's more a POC, unsuccessfull at the moment.

Comment: @UriGoren right, thanks. But that did not change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came here looking for the same answer as you and after tons of googling and trial and error I finally was able to perform exactly what you are attempting to do. I understand this is an old post but I did not see any answers that actually provided an answer that would allow what you are attempting to do work. I will use your example and try and apply what I had to change and add to get it to work properly.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    If CurrentProject.Connection.State = adStateOpen Then CurrentProject.Connection.Close

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open "select * from amsPor", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockBatchOptimistic

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If Not rs.ActiveConnection Is Nothing Then Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        If Not (rs.eof And rs.BOF) Then
            Set Me.Recordset = rs
        End If

        If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
            conn.Close
        End If
    End If

    Call AddNewRecord(Me.Recordset)
End Sub


Private Sub AddNewRecord(ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset)
    On Error Resume Next 

    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.Supports(adAddNew) Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("FirstName").Value = "John"
            rs.Fields("LastName").Value = "Doe"

            If rs.Supports(adUpdate) Then rs.Update
        End If
    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "AddNewRecord Err Msg: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Select Case MsgBox("Save changes ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)
    Case vbYes
        Call UpdateDbWithRS(Me.Recordset)
    Case vbCancel
        Cancel = True
    Case Else
        ' Nothing.
    End Select
End Sub


Private Sub UpdateDbWithRS(ByRef rs As ADODB.Recordset)
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If CurrentProject.Connection.State = adStateOpen Then CurrentProject.Connection.Close

        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
        rs.ActiveConnection = conn

        If rs.Supports(adUpdateBatch) Then
            rs.UpdateBatch

            If Not conn Is Nothing Then
                If conn.State = adStateOpen Then conn.Close
                Set conn = Nothing
            End If
            If Not rs Is Nothing Then
                If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
                Set rs = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

With the code above I was able to **Add** a **Record** to my **Recordset** and verify it did not show up in my database table. Then when I performed the **UpdateDbWithRS** the **Record** that I had added to the **Recordset**, previously, was now pushed to my database table.

The biggest changes I had to do with your code was changing `conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection` to `conn.Open CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString`, adding in the code `If CurrentProject.Connection.State = adStateOpen Then CurrentProject.Connection.Close` to fix the error I was receiving about the connection already being opened. Then the final biggest change I made was replacing your **CursorType** of `adOpenStatic` to `adOpenForwardOnly`. I am not sure if that last change is truly required but I used it based on a disconnected RecordSet example I found on this [Microsoft Support Site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/184397/how-to-create-ado-disconnected-recordsets-in-vba-c-java).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a disconnected recordset, you do not get the benefit of automatically updating changes to the tables. You need to actually run SQL Update and Insert Statements to save your data.

Comment: Isn'that the goal of `rs.UpdateBatch` ?

Comment: No, that assumes that the recordset is still connected and is Dynamic. Once you go with adOpenStatic its basically a snap shot and you can not use the recordset update or delete methods.

Comment: At this point you need to concatenate a SQL Update, Insert or Delete statements and execute them to make changes on your tables. That is the whole point of not keeping a constant connection to the data. You will also need to worry about changes made to the records you are about to modify which may have occurred in the time between you opened the recordset and when you are making changes, such as with multiple users and over writing each others work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code look perfect and should works as well, but...

**Solution 1**

As per my experience i'd suggest to forget about such of functionality. Several years ago i struggled with the same problem. I did not found any solution, but i'm almost sure that the access database used in multiuser environment could not be updated, because Jet/ACE engine does not allow to update static recordset when other user had made changes in a meanwhile (changes are rejected).

I resolved this issue by using "temporary table" binded with form:

```
DELETE * FROM ~TableName;
INSERT INTO ~TableName SELECT * FROM TableName;
```

User can edit records till Form is opened. On **Form_Unload** event i run query like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Field1 = t2.Field1,
Field1 = t2.Field2 ... and so on
FROM TableName As t1 INNER JOIN ~TableName AS t2 ON t1.Key = t2.Key
```

Note, that insertion and deletion of records (if its allowed) should be handled separately.

**Solution2**

Use dynamic cursor and does not disconnect recordset from database ;)
Catch changes by using [Form.Dirty property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194309%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: Solution 1 is interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you ;) I hope it might help.

Answer (score -4):

None of your code has anything to do with DISCONNECTED RECORDSETS. Your recordsets are connected. A disconnected recordset can be saved to file as xml or binary. There is no underlying database.

Note we make the disconnected recordset.

```
Sub Randomise
    Randomize 
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With rs
        .Fields.Append "RandomNumber", 4 

        .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
        .Open
        Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
            .AddNew
            .Fields("RandomNumber").value = Rnd() * 10000
            .Fields("Txt").value = Inp.readline
            .UpDate
        Loop
        .Sort = "RandomNumber"
        Do While not .EOF
            Outp.writeline .Fields("Txt").Value

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Here are the states

> ConnectionState
>
> The ConnectionState enumeration is used to identify the state of a connector space object. The CSEntry.ConnectionState property contains one of the values of this enumeration.
>
> Connected
>
> The connector space object is connected to a metaverse object.
>
> ExplicitlyConnected
>
> The connector space object is connected explicitly by a member of the MIISAdmins or MIISOperators group to a metaverse object by the account joiner.
>
> Disconnected
>
> The connector space object is not connected to an metaverse object but may be a candidate for connection to a metaverse object in the future.
>
> DisconnectedByFilter
>
> The connector space object was disconnected by the connector filter rules.
>
> Explicitly Disconnected 
>   The connector space object is not connected to a metaverse object and will not be a candidate for connection to a metaverse object in the future. 
>   Placeholder The connector space object exists implicitly in the connected directory, but has not been imported.

Comment: Then what do you call a recordset that you get from server, then you close the connection ?

Comment: I guess you will have to teach Microsoft what disconnected recordset are ? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184397/en-us

Comment: Well if you don't have experience of years. From *Accessing Recordsets over the Internet* From the March 2000 issue of MSDN Magazine `A connectionless (or custom) recordset is a recordset whose fields have been defined on the fly by the application to match the structure of the information you want it to manage. Previously this capability was reserved for the data object model, such as ADO 1.x, RDO, or DAO.` So note my sample code doing just this. I didn't bother reading the link you posted.

Comment: While the terminology used might be similar, the technique the OP is having problems with is entirely unrelated to the one you've demonstrated. Reading the linked article would have probably helped as it immediately clarifies that `A disconnected recordset is one of the powerful features of ADO wherein the connection is removed from a populated recordset. This recordset can be manipulated and again connected to the database for updating.` As it stands your 'answer' doesn't actually answer the question and your comment is rather rude.