# MS Access - Table locked by another person or process, after closing form

Tags: vba, ms-access, table-locking, record-locking

I am running a sub to 'snapshot' data from a pass-through query (which is slow) and store the results to a table. It is supposed to delete the table, then re-create it to be an updated snapshot of the pass-through query.

I know that before deleting the table I must close anything locking it. I only have one unbound form, and one subform on that which draws data from a query involving the table in question. I have a `DoCmd.close` action that closes the main form, but the line deleting the table still errors that it's 'in use by another person or process'.

How do I unlock it, is there more I should be doing other than closing the form?

Comment: Did you try changing the properties of the PTQ and set it to snapshot ?
That could avoid you to use a temp table completely.
Another way is to assign the recordset to the form (no table) like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27504015/78522

Comment: Does this code run in the form that's being closed? It may not be quite finished yet. Test this by running the form close code, then start the snapshot sub separately from the Debug window. Move it to a module if necessary.

Comment: Rather than deleting and re-creating the table, why not just delete the data with a simple `DELETE * FROM YourTable`.